# Google maps only one infoWindow

Tags: javascript, maps, infowindow

I've created some code to create a google map and it pulls in some marker data. How would I structure this code to only have a single Infowindow open at once? The more direct answer the better.

```
function initializeLocations(locations) {

        $.each(locations, function (i, location) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location.geo,
                map: map,
                title: location.name
            });

            var contentName = '<br><b>' + location.name + '</b><br>';
            var contentLink = '<a href="' + location.url + '">More Info</a>';
            var contentAddress = location.address;
            var content = contentName + contentAddress + contentLink

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: content
            });

            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.open(map, this);
            });
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Heres what i did.

```
function initializeLocations(locations) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    $.each(locations, function (i, location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location.geo,
            map: map,
            title: location.name
        });

        var contentName = '<br><b>' + location.name + '</b><br>';
        var contentLink = '<a href="' + location.url + '">More Info</a>';
        var contentAddress = location.address;
        var content = contentName + contentAddress + contentLink

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
            return function(){
                infoWindow.setContent(content);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker));
    });
}
```